# What are the fields which are non editable on a standard object?

Tags: apex

What are the fields which are non editable on a standard object like contact/lead?
example : ContactId/LeadId and formula fields are non editable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By following code you can ensure that the field is editable or not of contact object.

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> conMap = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.fields.getMap();
for(String fieldName : conMap.keySet()) {
   System.debug(fieldName + ' is editable ' + conMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().isUpdateable());
}
```

Comment: ahh you beat me.. I am about give ans to this question..

Answer (score 1):

To find non-editable fields follow the steps below:

- Firstly we have to view Standard object fields.
- In the Action column of the standard fields it is mentioned whether the field is editable or not.
       For more you can see the screenshots below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are the fields which can't be edited.

> Id, 
>   IsDeleted, 
>   CreatedById, 
>   CreatedDate, 
>   LastModifiedById,
>   LastModifiedDate,
>   SystemModstamp